# Stimulus Check Dependent Question

Tags: united-states, irs, covid-19, stimulus

In 2018, I was able to be claimed as a dependent, as listed on my tax return, but my parents didn’t claim me in 2018, in 2019 I was no longer a dependent.

Will I receive the check?

Comment: Will I receive the check?

Comment: Did you file your 2019 tax return? If you file your 2019 tax return, indicating that nobody can claim you as a dependent, you will qualify for the check.